# тире нужно где-нибудь?

Tags: пунктуация

что в Крыму есть большой запас сельхозтехники, приобретенной в 2015 году на сумму около 2 миллиардов рублей, и в 2016 году на сумму около полумиллиарда рублей.Тире нужно где-нибудь?

Answer (score 1):

...что в Крыму есть большой запас сельхозтехники, **приобретенной** (когда?) в 2015 году на сумму около 2 миллиардов рублей **и** в 2016 году на сумму около полумиллиарда рублей.

**Не нужно тире и запятой**, причастие управляет двумя обстоятельствами, соединенными одиночным союзом И.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Я думаю что тут не обязательно ставить тире. Потому что вы написали  "около". Если бы не было "около"  вы могли бы написать " сумму-2 миллиарда".